# Radeon R5 M230 driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, amd-graphics

I found some answers plus on the AMD Site that support for this Graphic Card is ended. Is there some other way to install this driver in order to use this card somehow?

Comment: `fglrx` is not supported by 18.04 due to incompatibility, AMD worked on improving radeon & amdgpu - https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-16.04-Dropping-fglrx